# HAVING LENGTH(field) in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to select rows with field `timestamp`, which has a length shorter than 16 characters. I've tried the following:

```
SELECT LENGTH(timestamp), id
FROM my_table
HAVING LENGTH(timestamp) < 16
```

But I get this error:

> #1054 - Unknown column 'timestamp' in 'having clause'

Any suggestions?

Comment: please use `SHOW CREATE TABLE my_table` and show us your actual table definition.

Comment: `CREATE TABLE \`my_table\` (
 \`id\` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 \`title\` text CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
 \`board_id\` int(11) NOT NULL,
 \`timestamp\` varchar(256) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
 \`comments_count\` int(11) NOT NULL,
 \`preview\` text CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
 \`expired\` int(11) NOT NULL,
 \`full\` mediumtext CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (\`id\`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1442 DEFAULT CHARSET=cp1251 COLLATE=cp1251_bin`

Comment: I found the solution. In early MySQL versions proper variant is
`SELECT LENGTH(\`timestamp\`) AS temp
FROM my_table
GROUP BY LENGTH(\`timestamp\`)
HAVING temp < 16`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you want:

```
SELECT LENGTH(`timestamp`), id
FROM my_table
WHERE LENGTH(`timestamp`) < 16
```

Or if you're actually trying to group the results...

```
SELECT LENGTH(`timestamp`)
FROM my_table
GROUP BY LENGTH(`timestamp`)
HAVING LENGTH(`timestamp`) < 16
```

Note the backticks (`) in each example to escape the column name.

Comment: Yes, I want first variant. I know that it's impossible to use aggregate functions in WHERE clause, so I tried to use HAVING. Anyway, if I add 'GROUP BY id' or 'GROUP BY LENGTH(timestamp)', nothing will change. I still get the same error, however required field definitely exists.

Comment: @user1235446 Make sure you're writing ` timestamp ` with the backtick character before and after (spaces here only for formatting, not required). `timestamp` is reserved in MySQL so you need to tell the parser to treat it as a field name explicitly.

Comment: Still get this error. Everything works when I use 'WHERE LENGHT('timestamp')<16' or even without backtick characters. Does that mean that MySQL doesn't follow SQL standard?

Comment: notice that the quotes around timestamp are not just regular single quotes. They are the the quotes that are on the same key as tilde in a US keyboard. The button under ESC.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will be worked to:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    LENGTH(timestamp)
FROM my_table
WHERE LENGTH(timestamp) < 16
```

Comment: This works, but I think it's not a good idea to use LENGTH in WHERE clause, because it contradicts sql standard, if I'm not mistaken.